# Print country with most people

Tags: java, java-stream

I have implemented this logic to print the country with most people. I have a Person class having age, country , name.

```
Map<String, Long> c = people.stream().collect((Collectors.groupingBy((Person::getCountry),(Collectors.counting()))));
Long f = Collections.max(c.values());
for (Map.Entry i : c.entrySet()) 
    if (i.getValue()==f)
        System.out.println(i.getKey() + " - " + i.getValue());
```

Can it be written in a shorter way?

Comment: For a starter, you could remove all the unnecessary brackets from the first line. Then, you can use `Map.Entry<String, Long> max = Collections.max(c.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue());` And for the future, keep in mind not to compare two `Long` objects using `==`. Use `equals` or declare the variable as `long`, to enforce a numerical comparison.

Comment: Shorter doesn't mean better. For example I set my `if` and `for,while...` statements always in curly brackets, because it's a common source for errors.
You also could split long statements into multiple lines to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var c = people.stream()
                .collect((Collectors.groupingBy((Person::getCountry), (Collectors.counting()))))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .max((o1, o2) -> Long.compare(o2.getValue(), o1.getValue())).get().getKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the two answers:

```java
var mostPopulousCountry = people.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCountry, Collectors.counting()))
   .entrySet().stream()
   .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
   .get().getKey();
```